# FontAwesome Pro and xamarin.ios only one font can be active

Tags: ios, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.ios

So I have been looking for an answer to this.

I can't get all 3 fonts in FontAwesome Pro to work with my xamarin native (iOS) to work.

I do use

```
UIFont.FromName(fontName, size);
```

But the "fontName" needs to be the "family"-name of the Font, which is a problem with FontAwesome because all versions in the pro edition got the same PostScript name. Its not the filename, its the family property of the font. So when I uses (on Mac) Fontbook, I can see that all three versions (Regular, Light and Solid) of the fontawesome pro, got the same family name, which is "Font Awesome 5 Pro".

So this means that I can only use one of the three fonts in the app.

I was looking for a solution to change the format, but I can't seem to find any way to do so. But if I could set which format I wanted the font to be in, then I wanted to define 'Light', 'Regular' or 'Solid' as font formats...

*Heres a screenshot from the Fontbook (Sorry it's in Danish)*

[image]

Comment: You can use them like this: 
Regular: UIFont.FromName("FontAwesome5ProRegular", size);
Solid: UIFont.FromName("FontAwesome5ProSolid", size);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those fonts also have *Postscript family name* defined you can use instead of the primary family name.

I do not have a pro license, but the free v5 show:

```
  * Font Awesome 5 Free
  *-- FontAwesome5FreeRegular
  *-- FontAwesome5FreeSolid
```

So you can:

```
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"FontAwesome5FreeSolid", 20);
var font = UIFont.FromName(@"FontAwesome5FreeRegular", 20);
```

FYI: To display those names, use the following:

```
foreach (var familyNames in UIFont.FamilyNames.OrderBy(c => c).ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(" * " + familyNames);
    foreach (var familyName in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(familyNames).OrderBy(c => c).ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" *-- " + familyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I was sure I had tested with the PostScript-name, but I must have done something wrong when I did. It now works, I got a FontHelper class to catch which font family needs to be used.

Comment: Thanks, also works with xamarin using Postscript family name

Comment: I found that the **Brands** collection which is now free is named `"FontAwesome5BrandsRegular"`

Comment: Leaving this here in case it helps anyone. The font names in this answer didn't work for me however I used your code to display the names and found "FontAwesome5Free-Solid" and "FontAwesome5Free-Regular" which did end up working. Downloaded these files from fontawesome in Nov 2019.

Comment: My font had a completely different name to what I was expecting! Your code helped me figure that out

Comment: I'm still having issues though. If you could spare time to help me, that would be wonderful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67490335/812013

Answer (score 2):

To use Font Awesome 5 Pro in Xamarin.Forms

Use it like below...
(Thanks to the helpful code of [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover))

- Font Awesome 5 Brands
  *-- FontAwesome5BrandsRegular
- Font Awesome 5 Pro
  *-- FontAwesome5ProLight
  *-- FontAwesome5ProRegular
  *-- FontAwesome5ProSolid

App.Xaml.cs

```
        Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        // Font awesome
        Current.Resources["FontawesomeSolid"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "Font Awesome 5 Pro" : "fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        Current.Resources["FontawesomeRegular"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "FontAwesome5Regular" : "fa-regular-400.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        Current.Resources["FontawesomeLight"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "FontAwesome5ProLight" : "fa-light-300.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        Current.Resources["FontawesomeBrands"] = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "FontAwesome5ProBrands" : "fa-brands-400.ttf#fFont Awesome 5 Pro";


        Current.Resources.Add("ShareIconLabel", new Style(typeof(Label))
        {
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.White},
                new Setter { Property = View.HorizontalOptionsProperty, Value = LayoutOptions.End},
                new Setter { Property = View.VerticalOptionsProperty, Value = LayoutOptions.Center},
                new Setter { Property = AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBoundsProperty, Value = new Rectangle (0.90, 0.5, 0.2, 1)},
                new Setter { Property = AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlagsProperty, Value = AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All},
                new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 30},
                new Setter { Property = Label.FontFamilyProperty, Value = Current.Resources["FontawesomeLight"] },
                new Setter { Property = Label.TextProperty, Value = "\uf1e0" } // Share Icon
            }
        });
```

MySharePage.Xaml

```
        <AbsoluteLayout
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,0.07"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="{x:Static localColors:Constants.MyOrange} ">
            <Label
                Style="{StaticResource ShareIconLabel}">
                <!--<Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="OnSocialShareClicked" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>-->
            </Label>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

iOS just loads the font by its 'PostScript Name'. You can rename your TTF file to match that PostScript name, then it will be easier to use it properly.