# How to use Font Awesome in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, font-awesome

I am trying to use **Font Awesome Icons** in my **Xamarin.iOS** project.

In my **Xamarin.Android** project it was pretty simple:

1. I downloaded the Font Awesome WebKit from [here](https://fontawesome.com/download)
2. I copied the ***.ttf-Files*** of the fonts I want to use in my Assets folder

[image]

3. I create a new **Typeface** for my TextView with the font and use the unicode of the icon

**Code:**

```
var myIcon = new TextView(Context);
var regularFont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf");
myIcon.SetTypeface(regularFont, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
myIcon.Text = "\uf007";
```

[image]

I can change TextColor, BackgroundColor, etc. like a normal text.

**My problem** is, I can't figure out, **how to use Font Awesome in my Xamarin.iOS project**. Most tutorials and How-Tos are directed to Xamarin.Forms. I tried to merge many of these approaches, but it failed.

The only approach I found is to draw the .svg-Files with SkiaSharp, but that is no option for my use case.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86333/font-awesome-not-working-in-ios

Comment: Place in your Resources folder, and ensure the build type is `BundleResource` . Check https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188187/fontawesome-pro-and-xamarin-ios-only-one-font-can-be-active/48191854#48191854

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT as the title of your helpthread says forms and I'm not working with .xml Files in Xamarion.iOS I have not considered this page

Comment: @SushiHangover indeed, if I only load one fontawesome, it works :) I'll keep you updated, when I'm able to display all fonts

Comment: Did u add UIAppFonts in info.Plist

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya yep, it already works.. i just have to wait to accept my own answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FontAwesome Pro and xamarin.ios only one font can be active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188187/fontawesome-pro-and-xamarin-ios-only-one-font-can-be-active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SushiHangovers comment leads me to the solution for my problem.

[FontAwesome Pro and xamarin.ios only one font can be active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188187/fontawesome-pro-and-xamarin-ios-only-one-font-can-be-active/48191854#48191854)

It was not possible to use 3 Font Awesome fonts at the same time in the **Designer**, but it works when they are used during runtime via code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add .ttf files in your Xamarin iOS project (I have added it in resources)
2. Now `inside info.plist Add a new key “Fonts provided by application”`
3. Expand the array, and in string value add your fontname (eg: fa-solid-900.ttf) which you have added in your project
   Setup Done:
   Now Just wherever you want to add fontawesome icon just `select font awesome as font family`  in storyboard but `make sure to add text programmatically`